# Encode and decode a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, decode, encode

Let's say I have a string, called `str`, which is equal to "Hello, world!"
Is there a way to choose some unicode characters like `"azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn1234567890-"` and return an encoded string that contains only the choosen characters?
It should return something like "hvfebi iehfhe" (well, something encoded and not human readable, but which is decodable)?
Thanks

Comment: You could use real encryption and base64 encode the result.

Comment: Oh I forgot to add, something not like base64, something which isn't popular and so not decodable without having the function to do it

Comment: base64 isn't popular?  What in the world?  `not decodable without having the function`  The same goes for *any* encoding scheme.  Plus, JavaScript has these functions *built-in*.  Can the same be said for your custom encoding scheme?

Comment: @Amy he doesn't want base64 because it IS popular. He should be looking into encryption, not encoding.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such a thing as a function that you configure an arbitrary set of characters to enconde and decode, unless you find a library that does that or you implement it yourself.

But, you can use base64 encoding, which uses "A-Z", "a-z", "0-9", "+", "/" and "=" characters to encode the string.
The native browser functions are on window: btoa() to enconde and atob() to decode.

Edit after your comments: 
Any function you make up to solve this will be decodable anyway analysing the code, so no point in hiding it. If you don't want to be simply base64, you can make a function that encodes it several times.

Comment: I need something that nobody can decode except if they have the set of unicode characters `"azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn1234567890-"`

Comment: You can't make a secure substitution algorithm on the frontend. Anyone can debug your code and get your string.